# Multiple Selects from Subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have multiple queries that look like this:

```
select count(*) from (
  SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t 
  JOIN TABLE2 e 
  USING (EVENT_ID)
) s1
WHERE
s1.SOURCE_ID = 1;
```

where the only difference is the `t1.SOURCE_ID = (some other number)`. I would like to turn these into a single query that just selects from the subquery using a different `SOURCE_ID` for each column in the result, like this:

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| source_1_count | source_2_count | source_3_count | ... so on
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I am trying to avoid using the multiple queries as the join is on a very large table and takes some time, so I would rather do it once and query the result multiple times.

This is on a Snowflake data warehouse which I think uses something similar to PostgreSQL (also I'm fairly new to SQL so feel free to suggest a completely different solution as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT sum(case when sourceid=1 then 1 else 0 end) source_1_count, sum(case when sourceid=2 then 1 else 0 end) source_2_count...
  FROM TABLE1 t 
  JOIN TABLE2 e 
  USING (EVENT_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would put the results in separate rows, using `group by`:

```
SELECT SOURCE_ID, COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE1 t JOIN
     TABLE2 e 
     USING (EVENT_ID)
GROUP BY SOURCE_ID;
```

Putting the separate sources in columns is troublesome, unless you know the exact list of sources that you want in the result set.

EDIT:

If you know the exact list of sources, you can use conditional aggregation or `pivot`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN SOURCE_ID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as source_id_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SOURCE_ID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as source_id_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SOURCE_ID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as source_id_3
FROM TABLE1 t JOIN
     TABLE2 e 
     USING (EVENT_ID);
```

Comment: I actually do know the exact list of sources, it's available elsewhere in the code. How would I go about it that way then?

Answer (score 0):

All the comments so far ignore the fact that you won't have the possible benefits of pruning the data during the scan, as there are no `WHERE` predicates. Join can also be slower than it needs to be because of that.

This is a possible improvement:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN SOURCE_ID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as source_id_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SOURCE_ID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as source_id_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SOURCE_ID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as source_id_3
FROM TABLE1 t JOIN
     TABLE2 e 
     USING (EVENT_ID);
WHERE SOURCE_ID IN (1, 2, 3)
```